# how to pass glob string to ffmpeg from a bash function?

Tags: linux, bash, ffmpeg

I'm trying to create an animation from a group of png
files `prefix_XXXX.png` in a directory (where X is a digit 0-9).  This creates the file foo.mp4:

```
ffmpeg -nostdin -r 2 -pattern_type glob  -i './prefix_*.png' -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p foo.mp4
```

I want to place my command in a bash function so I don't have to
dig all the ffmpeg args out of my bash history everytime.  I suspect I'm
not quoting the glob string correctly:

```
function wrf_animate()  {
    # usage: wrf_animate files_to_animate_glob_string name_of_output.mp4
    echo "running in $PWD"
    echo " ==== "
    ls -lh $1
    echo " ==== "
    ffmpeg -nostdin -r 2 -pattern_type glob  -i "$1" -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p $2
}
```

The echo and ls lines in the above function show I'm running in
the right place and the args are making it in.

$1, "$1", \'"$1"\' all result in: "File 'prefix_0100.png' already exists. Exiting."

"\'$1\'" results in: \'prefix_0000.png\': No such file or directory

\'$1\' results in: 'prefix_0000.png': No such file or directory

Comment: How are you calling your function? Also, don't forget to quote `"$2"`.

Comment: `wrf_animate prefix_*.png foo.mp4`.  I've also tried single and double quotes around `prefix_*.png`.

Comment: Weird, it should work when called like `wrf_animate "prefix_*.png" "foo.mp4"` and when `"$1"`/`"$2"` are quoted (as it's written in question).

Comment: In `wrf_animate prefix_*.png foo.mp4`, the glob is expanded **before the function is run**; thus, the function is invoked as something like `wrf_animate prefix_0001.png prefix_0002.png prefix_0003.png foo.mp4`. If you want to pass the glob as `$1`, you need to quote it at call time: `wrf_animate 'prefix_*.png' foo.mp4`.

Comment: BTW, running `set -x` before calling your function is likely to be helpful in debugging this kind of situation.

Comment: thanks, @randomir...  double quoting the `"prefix_*.png"` on the command line did the trick.  It doesn't seem to matter whether I quote $2 within the function or not.  I must not have tried the double quoted `"prefix_*.png"` in the command *without* single quotes on `$1` inside the function.  Arg...  I'm not a bash expert obviously.  If you submit your solution as an answer I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDuffy - the reminder of expansion order explains why the unquoted `prefix_*.png` argument made it through the `ls` line OK; this was helpful to me.  I'm not a bash ninja as you can tell, but I think I now understand why my various tries did or didn't work.

Comment: @TimothyW.Hilton, you're welcome. In shell programming, [always remember to quote](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes).